# What is a thread-safe way to break out of a POCO::HTTPSClientSession::receiveResponse?

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, poco-libraries

The receiveResponse call is blocking, and while I run the code on a separate thread, I'd like to be able to cleanly stop the thread at any time. The documentation shows abort() may be what I need, but I can't find any information indicating whether it's thread-safe or not.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPSClientSession::abort() calls shutdown() on the socket; that should cause receiveResponse() to return (CORRECTION: to [throw](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/src/HTTPClientSession.cpp#L249)).

HTTP(S)ClientSession has no internal locking but thread-safety here is not really a Poco-related question. If it is safe to call shutdown() on a socket blocked on recv() for your platform/stack, then all is good.

Comment: Could you explain how you mean 'thread-safety here is not really a Poco-related question'? I have no access to the POCO source, so it's impossible for me to tell exactly what happens both during the receiveResponse and when calling abort/shutdown.
Also I'm not sure how to know whether it's safe to call shutdown on a socket blocked on recv - when wouldn't it be?

Comment: Everyone has access to Poco source, see https://github.com/pocoproject/poco . 

As for whether it is safe to call shutdown on a blocked socket that is indeed not a Poco question because Poco does not implement sockets but only wraps them and how recv() and shutdown() interact may be platform-specific (no information on platform in the question). The answer explains what happens "under the hood". See e.g. these answers:
http://fixunix.com/unix/374842-shutdown-while-blocking-recv-send-select.html#post989156
http://fixunix.com/unix/374842-shutdown-while-blocking-recv-send-select.html#post990497

Comment: @Alex It should cause a throw because of premature EOS, not because of a network exception as the code you linked to appears to implement. And does abort() shutdown the input? And where is it defined?

Comment: As for shutdown(), it shuts down both in and out; there are also separate shutdownSend() and shutdownReceive() functions. Socket::shutdown() is defined here: https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/src/SocketImpl.cpp#L254